# Check if ordered on date not working correctly

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

I have 2 functions and a reservation page.

My check function:

```
    $sqlres = 'SELECT * FROM reserveren  WHERE (
        ? BETWEEN resvan AND restot
        OR ? BETWEEN resvan AND restot
        ) AND accomodatie=?';

    if($stmt = $con->myconn->prepare($sqlres)){
        $stmt->bind_param('ssi', $resvan, $restot,$accomodatie);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
    }
    if ($stmt->fetch()){
        $errmsg[] = "already reserveerd!";
        return $errmsg;
    }
```

My order function:

```
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO reserveren (accomodatie,land_id,personen,userid,resvan,restot,park) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)';

    if ($stmt = $con->myconn->prepare($sql))
    {
        $stmt->bind_param('sisisss', $accomodatie,$landid,$personen,$userid,$resvan, $restot,$park);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
    }
    else{
        die("errormessage: " . $con->myconn->error);
    }
```

my order Page:

```
if (isset($_POST['res']) && $_POST['res'] === 'reserveer') {
    $personen = $_POST['personen'];
    $resvan = $_POST['resvan'];
    $restot = $_POST['restot'];
    $accomodatie = $_POST['accomodatie'];
    $park = $_POST['park'];
    $userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
    $landid = $_POST['landid'];
    $errorMsgs = $user->check($resvan, $restot,$accomodatie);
    if (empty($errorMsgs)) {
        $user->reserveer($accomodatie,$landid,$personen,$userid,$resvan, $restot,$park);
        echo '<div class="alert alert-success"  role="alert"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">x</span></button>You have succesfully made a reservation.</div>';
        exit;
    }

    foreach ($errorMsgs as $msg) {
        echo '<li>'. $msg. '</li>';
    }

}
```

Everything works correct but there's 1 flaw in my code.

1st:

Let's say someone made a reservation from 2001-01-15 to 2001-01-15 it gives a successful message and it gets reserved. And then someone makes a reservation from 2001-01-14 to 2001-01-16 it gives a successful message and it gets reserved as well. While it shouldn't get reserved since there is already a reservation on the 15th.

2nd:

If it happens the other way from 14 to 16 then from 15 to 15 it gives a error message that its already ordered. So that works correctly.

How can I make it work that it gives the error message that its ordered if it's the 1st way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine Logic for MySQL Select - Reservation System](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302066/determine-logic-for-mysql-select-reservation-system)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your query to this:

```
'SELECT * FROM reserveren  WHERE (
    ? <= restot
    AND ? >= resvan 
    ) AND accomodatie=?';
```

I assumed the first parameter is the start date and the second one is the end date of the new reservation, same for `restot`(end) and `resvan`(start)

This will catch all overlapping reservations.

Comment: resvan is start and restot is end.

Comment: @DannyO yea, my bad , that's what I meant

Comment: Shouldn't you use AND instead of OR?

Comment: @sagi This used to be my old query. But this doesn't work. It has to check between both dates. and this query is too less for it.

Comment: @DannyO No its not, try it again, used OR instead of AND

Comment: @sagi Oh wait you're right. I just tested it again it works correctly. Thank you so much!